# Get the column letter from excel PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to get the column letter.

takes_column(item) is a method that should return the letter. The reason of this is to write in my DB the rigth column.

```
for ($i=2;$i<=$filas;$i++){

    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['item'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(takes_column(item).$i)->getCalculatedValue();

    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['warehouse'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(takes_column(item).$i)->getCalculatedValue();

    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['item_description'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(takes_column(item).$i)->getCalculatedValue();

    } 

}


function takes_column($input)
{

$row = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator(0)->current();

$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();

$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {

    if ($cell->getValue() = $input){

        return $cell->getColumn();

    }
}
```

Comment: In PHP, you use `==` for comparison; not `=`, which is for assignment

Comment: But what is `item`? The argument that you're passing to `takes_column()`? And why are you using `item` whatever you're checking against?

Comment: I dont need to use item?

Comment: Coudl I just return something without passing a value?

Comment: The question is, what are you trying to do? There's a lot of problems with your code that make it difficult to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: You can return whatever you want from `takes_column()` but what do you __need__ to be returned, and how do you decide what should be returned?

Comment: Im trying to get the column letter.

Comment: If I have lets say

columnA columnB ColumnC

Basically,
What Im sending is the value of the column. Ex: columnA
and this one will return A as a letter for the column

Comment: So, Even if I change the column, the method will match the positions

Comment: So explain what item is? Is it a string? (in which case, it should be quoted as a string like `'item'`) Is it a variable? (in which case it should be `$item`) Is it a constant? Are you trying to work out the column letter that the value `item` appears in, regardless of what row it might appear in?

Comment: Yes, It is a string. I should be able to write in my DB regardless the positon of he column Item, warehouse and item_description

Comment: Well, PHP strings should be quoted.... and why are you using the same string for `item`, `warehouse` and `item_description`

Comment: And is this `item` string anywhere in the spreadsheet, or is it a heading in the first row?

Comment: Yes only the first row. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Vaguely, but it's hopelessly inefficient.... you should map the column names ___before___ your main loop

Answer (score 2):

Map your column names into a lookup array ***before*** your main loop:

```
$headingData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->rangeToArray(
        'A1:A' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn(),
        null, true, true, true
    );
$headings = array_flip($headingData[1]);
```

This should give you an array something like:

```
[
    'item' => 'A',
    'warehouse' => 'B',
    'item_description' => 'C',
]
```

And you can then do a lookup against that headers array in your loop:

```
for ($i=2;$i<=$filas;$i++){
    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['item'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($headings['item'].$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['warehouse'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($headings['warehouse'].$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['item_description'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($headings['item_description'].$i)->getCalculatedValue();
}
```